# How can I get the amount of readyboost RAM?

Tags: c#, .net, ram

***Question***

How to get amount of readyboost RAM in C#?

***Background Info***

Alright, so I am using C# and I want to get the amount of RAM in a computer.  There are 3 boxes, amount of installed RAM, amount of virtual/readyboost cache, and the total.

I was able to successfully get the installed memory, and the virtual memory showed up too but with the wrong amount.

***Problem***

I have a flash drive with 4GB dedicated to readyboost.  First of all, I had it unplugged and tested the program. 2GB of virtual RAM, I guess there was something on the hard drive or something, was sure I saw it before.

I plugged in the flash drive and waited...

Then I booted up the program.  There was still 2GB of virtual RAM, despite me plugging in my flash drive.

***What I have tried so far***

Here is the refresh button code.  It is the same code that is in Form1_Load.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo ci = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo();

    label3.Text = System.Convert.ToString(ci.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1000000000) + "GB";
    label5.Text = System.Convert.ToString((ci.TotalVirtualMemory + ci.TotalPhysicalMemory) / 1000000000) + "GB";
    label7.Text = System.Convert.ToString(ci.TotalVirtualMemory / 1000000000) + "GB";
}
```

Comment: ReadyBoost does not change the amount of virtual memory available. It is a duplicate of the existing page file.

Comment: `TotalVirtualMemory` is completely unrelated to ReadyBoost or any other caching mechanism.  It is talking about the virtual memory space available to your process from the OS, which on Windows is almost always 2GB.